# Date does not display properly while export from IE

Tags: angularjs, excel, internet-explorer-11, angular-ui-grid

Please find below code:

```
        var sReportDate = new Date();
        var sReportFormattedDate = sReportDate.toDateString() + " " + sReportDate.toLocaleTimeString() + " " + sReportDate.toString().match(/([A-Z]+[\+-][0-9]+.*)/)[1];
        sTitle = sTitle + "\nReport Extracted on:" + sReportFormattedDate +"\n\n";
        return sTitle;
```

The code formats the date. And the returned value is used in exported csv of `angular-ui-grid`.

When I export the grid from `chrome` and opens `csv` file in `MS Excel`, the date displays properly. But when I export the same grid from `IE 11` and opens the `csv` file in `MS Excel`, the date displays with so many special characters.

The below statement displays the date in correct format on `IE 11` console:

```
var sReportFormattedDate = sReportDate.toDateString() + " " + sReportDate.toLocaleTimeString() + " " + sReportDate.toString().match(/([A-Z]+[\+-][0-9]+.*)/)[1];
```

`Tue Sep 22 2015 ‎3‎:‎17‎:‎35‎ ‎PM GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)`

But while export from `IE 11`, the time portion (string between 2015 and PM) displays many special characters in `MS Excel`.

**Why `toLocaleTimeString` is exported properly from Chrome and why is it not exported properly from IE11 ?**

**How do I display the date in proper format while export from `IE 11` ?**